# C++ template type circularity and non-template pointer to template instance

Tags: c++, templates, events, variadic-templates, circular-dependency

For reference, here is the minimal example : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75354688a0a6af64

In this example, I have a single problem of template type circularity that, in my view, could be solved in two ways :

- make the `Controller` a template class and the `Event` member pointer a non-template pointer to a template class instance (**but how ?**)
- use `std::any` or something like it to keep the `Controller` class non-template (like is shown in the example, but doesn't compile)

What is the best way to make this work in a cleanly ?

EDIT : link updated

Comment: The minimal example is a bit hard to follow since there are a lot of other issues. All classes only have private members, there are a handful typos, iostream include is missing and for-range on a tuple does not work are some errors I found. Can you update the example so that the problems is isolated?

Comment: Just to get this straight: You have a `Controller`, containing several `Module`s, each of which is defined with a different pack of `EventHandler`?

Comment: @MikaelH I updated the link. I hope I fixed most errors, please feel free to suggest any improvement to the minimal example.

Comment: @BennyK, exactly. The functions in the eventHandlers need access to the controllers they belong to

Comment: "The functions in the eventHandlers need access to the controllers" - this feels like a design issue. Doing exactly what you tried to do is probably a lost cause.
Why don't you try explaining the end result, and I'll see if I can figure out a better design

Comment: @BennyK It's all about being able to trigger events for the controller and let the controller modules (and thus, their event handlers) handle them with custom user-provided code. I need to be able to trigger events from the event handlers which would create an implicit event loop. Thanks for your help, we can bring it to chat if you wish

Comment: I may have something to contibute from a project of mine, but i'm not sure how to use it in your case. Chat sounds good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216927/discussion-between-benny-k-and-magix).

Comment: I patched some more fixes and commented out the underlying issue. I don't have a good suggestion for a solution, but maybe someone else can see it better now (?): https://godbolt.org/z/P4JZ_o.

Comment: Working [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e83c33b7238af9e8) with `std::any`.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. I cannot thank you enough, but I can encourage you to explain how it works in an answer I can accept ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 pretty sure your demo code causes a stack overflow when trying to access the `_modules` variable (that went out of scope) from the lambda. I can't find a way to fix it yet

Comment: I capture by copy in `func`, so it should be OK.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's weird I have a stack overflow here, can't find the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fully type erase functor which accept template argument.

But if you know the subset of template argument to handle, `std::any`/ `std::variant` might help:

In your case non-supported event do no-op, so "your" controller:

```
template <typename ... Modules>
class Controller {
public:
    std::tuple<Modules...> modules;
        
    template<typename evt_t>
    void emit(evt_t event) { 
        std::apply([this](auto&&... args) {((args.dispatch(Event<evt_t>{event, this})), ...);}, modules);
    }
        
    Controller(std::tuple<Modules...> _modules) : modules{_modules}{}
};
```

becomes

```
class Controller {
    std::function<void(std::any)> func;
public:
    template<typename evt_t>
    void emit(evt_t event) {
        func(event);
    }

    template <typename ... Modules, typename EventTags>
    Controller(std::tuple<Modules...> tmodules, EventTags event_tags)
    {
        func = [=, this](std::any any_ev){
            auto f = [&, this](auto tag){
                using EventType = typename decltype(tag)::type;
                if (auto* ev = std::any_cast<EventType>(&any_ev)) {
                    std::apply([=, this](auto&&... modules) {((modules.dispatch(Event<EventType>{*ev, this})), ...);}, tmodules);
                }
            };
            std::apply([&f](auto... tags){ (f(tags), ...); }, event_tags);
        };
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e83c33b7238af9e8)

Comment: This only works if `tmodules` is copy-constructible, right ? I'm struggling because `Module`  instances are only moveConstructible and moveAssignable

Comment: With C++14, you might move-capture instead of copy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be not what you think it is.

```
std::vector<std::any> modules;
//...
    for(auto mod : modules) { mod.dispatch(Event{event, this}); } // should probably use an algorithm here
```

First you cannot iterate a `tuple` like that. Secondly `any` doesn't have a dispatch method.

Comment: Updated the minimal example to fix this. The essential problem is the templating of the `Controller`  class and its ripples on the `EventHandler`  and `Event` classes

Comment: @Magix can you please make the  example concrete without the "?..." - its hard to see the issue by eye.

Comment: The issue is 'what do I put instead of the `?...` ?'

Comment: @Magix whatever you intended, I don't care if it doesn't compile - its better than half done

Comment: @Magix It just occurred to me: perhaps you just need use `std::function` instead over-templating ?